# Persistent memory objects - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have been using 'sdbm' to manage some key-value stores to help improve the application response time, and reduce pressure on the MySQL server. My code is a little bit clunky (due to the nature of SDBM) and the key-value stores SDBM creates are not in-memory data structures, but rather saved to the file system (or at least this is my understanding of SDBM).

I realize that there's Memecached or Redis that can be used, but this is probably an overkill for my application. Are there any recommendations for something in-between?

I realize that there is no code in my question, but I imagine that this is a coding pre-requisite if you want an application that performs well and allows you to have a smaller footprint (less memory and less expensive CPU), which is what programmers should seek.

Comment: Another troll downvotes the question without leaving a comment as to why they did it.

Answer (score 2):

Memcache and Redis have easy to use, established gems that make doing what you're looking for trivial.  In my eyes, rolling your own system for something that has existing solutions is far more overkill than just installing memcache.

In Rails, it's literally 1 line of configuration in an initializer, and you can start using the Rails.cache methods.

Comment: What about memory usage / CPU usage if Memcached is used. I realize that Mecached and Redis are easy to use from a coding perspective.

Comment: Redis is third party - no memory consumption for you

Comment: I don't know the scale of your application so it's hard to gauge memory usage... Best way is to test!